# apt upgrades only some packages in my repository

Tags: debian, apt

I have two repositories containing each a set of nearly identical packages. The difference is that the packages in the first repository are build for Debian "jessie" while the packages in the second repository are build for Debian "buster". But apart from that, if you pick the package `my-package` in the first repository, and the same package `my-package` in the second repository, they have the same version number, description, maintainer, and other metadata.

I have a machine running Debian "jessie" with installed packages from the first repository. I upgraded this machine to Debian "buster", then changed my `sources.list` so my packages are pulled from the second repository instead. I then run `apt update` and `apt upgrade`.

At this point, I wasn't sure if it would work since as I mentioned, jessie and buster packages have the same version number. But it worked and indeed some packages were upgraded.

This is where I don't understand what's happening because only SOME packages are upgraded. When I try to specifically upgrade the packages that were not upgraded by running `apt upgrade my-package` for example, I get the following message:

```
my-package is already the newest version (2.0.0-0).
```

I'm not sure how I could investigate this issue further and understand why some packages are upgraded but not the others.

**EDIT**

This is the outcome of `apt policy my-package`:

```
my-package:
  Installed: 2.0.0-0
  Candidate: 2.0.0-0
  Version table:
 *** 2.0.0-0 500
        500 http://company.packages.net/buster rc/company amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

I changed the names obviously, but that's the gist of it. I have a similar output for every other packages.

Comment: you can see all available versions with `apt policy my-package` or if you feel cool use aptitude

Comment: @MaxMuster I tried that for a package that was upgraded and for another package that wasn't. The output was identical.

Comment: show me the output of `apt policy my-package`

Comment: @MaxMuster I edited my post to include the output of `apt policy my-package`.

Comment: please use official debian repositories in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` or official mirrors. https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake when writing my question, it's not in `/etc/apt/sources.list` but in a file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`.

Comment: the output of `apt policy` shows that the package `my-package` is not served multiple times, but only once in the unofficial repository `company.packages.net`. This package is not served by official Debian repositories.

Comment: I am aware of that. This is one of my own packages, hosted on my own repository. What's the issue?